# Tokenizing a dataframe of song lyrics

Tags: r, nlp, token, tokenize

I have a csv data file of song lyrics where each row is a sentence. I can read this in and use the unnest_tokens function to break the dataframe into a new data frame where each row is a word. Now I am trying to only tokenize the first few rows of the dataframe instead of the whole thing. So, I thought I could just make a new subframe using an index and then use the same function but no luck:

```
#Works on the whole dataframe

library(dplyr)
library(tokenizers)
library(tidytext)


biggie <- read.csv("C:/Users/First.Last/Desktop/biggie.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

colnames(biggie)[1] <- 'biggie'



bigsplit <- biggie %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, biggie)
```

At first I thought the issue was that indexing changed the original dataframe from a list to a character. So, I added an extra step to turn the subset back into a dataframe. When I test the object types with typeof() they all came back as lists so I thought it would work when I run it through the unnest_tokens line. However, I get this error when I run the lines:

Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.

```
#Here is where it breaks

bigtest <- biggie[1:10,]
bigtest <- data.frame(bigtest)
colnames(bigtest) <- 'biggie'

bigind <- bigtest %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, 'biggie')
```

I'm really stumped on what the issue is here. In my relatively limited knowledge, this seems like it should work fine. I'd love any input anyone might have.

```
summary(bigtest)
```

[image: summary of bigtest]

Comment: Are you tied to R? Most of these text-based problems are solved a lot more easily in e.g. Python

Comment: Relatively tied. R is the only software I've ever worked with so I'd be starting from scratch in python.

Comment: This works fine for me on a toy set. Are you sure your input dataset is clean / consistent? Can you post an extract and a "summary()" of your data?

Comment: For extra credit, can you try running this: `bigsplit <- unnest_tokens(tbl = bigtest, output = "token", input = "biggie")`

Comment: I get this when I run your extra credit line: Error in unnest_tokens.data.frame(tb1 = bigtest, output = "token", input = "biggie") : 
  argument "tbl" is missing, with no default

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by extract, but maybe this link to the data will help? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/133AzsjbEhImCbsp0aVa0KaxDmBEMP3VXfAhalhzmuYw/edit?usp=sharing

And here is an example of what comes up for the summary run - It seems like there is some problem:

NULL: Strictly for live men, not for freshmen

Comment: aha, re: the first answer, the argument is `tbl`, with an `l` not  `1`.

Comment: re the second, can you post the output of summary() here; and then running `bigtest = na.omit(bigtest)` before you do the `unnest()` command.

Comment: I added the summary() results above and this is what I get when I correct the tbl command and run na.omit() first: Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.